# Sylow subgroups of abelian profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

If $G$ is a finite abelian group, then we have a decomposition
$$G\cong \prod_{p} G(p)$$
where $G(p)$ is the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. This product makes sense as for all but finitely many primes $p$, we have $G_p=\{0\}$. This is proven by showing that the cardinality of $G$ and $\prod_{p} G(p)$ agree. If we now assume that $P$ is a profinite abelian group, there still exists the notion of a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P(p)$ which is now a pro-$p$-group. I'm curious if there exists an isomorphism
$$P\cong \prod_{p} P(p).$$

Comment: One can verify this by computing indices as 'supernatural numbers', in the sense of Serre's "Galois cohomology"; but probably easier is to consider the maps $P \to P(p)$ given by $g \mapsto \lim_{N \to \infty} g^{p^N - 1}$, where $N \to \infty$ in the divisibility order.  (I might also consider calling your profinite group something other than $P$, which looks like a pro-$p$ group ….)

Comment: Oh, by the way there is a very natural proof for finite groups, which consists in proving that the natural map $\prod_p G(p)\to G$ is a group isomorphism (rather than computing cardinalities).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Proposition 2.3.8 of [Ribes and Zaleskii - Profinite groups (second edition)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-01642-4).  (I originally gave references specifically for the finer structure of profinite Abelian groups, but assuming finite generation, in Section 4.3 of the same book.)

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the non-finitely generated case. Does anyone know more about that case?

Comment: It turns out those Section 4.3 references were mainly about the finer structure of pro-$p$ groups.  I modified now to cite Proposition 2.3.8, which is about pronilpotent groups in general (no finite generation hypotheses).  Sorry for the confusion!